# First struct of returning array is empty

Tags: java, arrays, struct, jna

Im trying to build a C++ library that can be used from Java via JNA. I'm doing some tests to return an array of Structs. I've created the following struct:

C++:

```
namespace structures
{
    typedef struct _Point {
        int x, y;
    } Point;
}
```

Java:

```
public class Point extends Structure {
    public Point() {
    // required for toArray()
    }

    public Point(Pointer pointer) {
    super(pointer);
    }

    public int x, y;
}
```

So, I have a C++ method that returns an array of points:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) structures::Point* getPoints(){
    structures::Point *p;
    p = (structures::Point *) malloc( 4 * sizeof(structures::Point) );
    p[0].x = 10;
    p[0].y = 20;
    p[1].x = 30;
    p[1].y = 40;
    p[2].x = 50;
    p[2].y = 60;
    p[3].x = 70;
    p[3].y = 80;
    return p ;
```

And in Java this is the interface that declares the library access:

```
public interface Multiplyt extends Library{
    Pointer getPoints();
}
```

And this is the code that tests the library:

```
Pointer pointer = test.getPoints();
Point point, points[];
point = new Point(pointer);
points = (Point[]) point.toArray(4);
System.out.println("0x:"+points[0].x + " 0y:" + points[0].y + " 1x:"+ points[1].x + " 1y:" + points[1].y);
System.out.println("2x:"+points[2].x + " 2y:" + points[2].y + " 3x:"+points[3].x + " 3y:" + points[3].y);
```

The output for those commands is:

```
0x:0 0y:0 1x:30 1y:40
2x:50 2y:60 3x:70 3y:80
```

So as you can see, the Point Structure at position 0 has no values for x or y (it has 0 and 0 and it should be 10 and 20). Why is this happening? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Structure data is uninitialized because you never call Structure.read() after initializing the structure from a pointer value.

JNA will in some instances implicitly call Structure.read() for you, such as before/after a native function call, or when expanding a single structure into an array backed by the same memory.  In the latter case, however, your first element is uninitialized because JNA assumes it to already be initialized when you call toArray() on it.

When you declare your function to return a Structure rather than a Pointer, JNA can guess that it needs to call Structure.read() for you.

Comment: Thanks. Calling ".read()" on point after calling to array also makes the avobe code work. I also tried to declare the interface in Java to return a Struct Point, leaving the C++ code the same, and it also works without the need to call point.read().

Comment: In this case, you should call Structure.read() in your Structure(Pointer) constructor, before calling .toArray().  Once JNA knows that the structure is the first element of an array, it auto reads and writes the remaining elements whenever Structure.read()/.write() is called as part of Structure auto-read/write functionality.  So you should do the read in the constructor or before calling toArray() to avoid the redundant read.

Answer (score 0):

for the reason of your struct return is the Pointer,so you must tell jna that the return type is struct pointer,you must declare that you implement the Structure.ByReference and Structure.ByValue

```
public class Point extends Structure {
public static class ByReference extends Point implements Structure.ByReference { }

public static class ByValue extends Point implements Structure.ByValue{ }

public Point() {
// required for toArray()
}

public Point(Pointer pointer) {
    super(pointer);
}

public int x, y;
}
```

then

```
public interface Multiplyt extends Library{
Point.ByReference getPoints();
}
```

the Point.ByReference is the same as Point* in C language that jna can parse

```
Point.ByReference pointer = test.getPoints();
Point points[];
points = (Point[]) pointer.toArray(4);
System.out.println("0x:"+points[0].x + " 0y:" + points[0].y + " 1x:"+ points[1].x + " 1y:" + points[1].y);
System.out.println("2x:"+points[2].x + " 2y:" + points[2].y + " 3x:"+points[3].x + " 3y:" + points[3].y);
```

Comment: It's perfectly working. Thank you. If I want to free the memory allocated with malloc, would it be enough to implement a method that does free(pt), where pt is a Point* which corresponds to the "pointer" object in java?

Comment: The ByReference and ByValue definitions/usage is only required if you want to use the non-default semantics.  By default, structure return values and arguments are treated as by reference, while structures nested within other structures are treated as by value.

Comment: While the solution is technically correct, your explanation does not indicate *why* it fixes the issue, as well as introducing extraneous elements which are irrelevant to the issue.